# How to activate Javascript(Angularjs) variable intellisense in html

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I have a variable in js. I want to get it from html page by intellisense.

**js Code :**

`var buyer ="Addidas";` in js file.

Now I want to get it in html body as intellisense.

```
{{buyer}}
```

Comment: link it to scope. don't add it as new variable.

Comment: Intellisense just doesn't come in javascript by default. you manually have to make it which seems to be tougher task (at least for me till date). When you work with js file, bowser's cache could help you to get entered detail. but if you expect to have intellisense provided in(.NET), its not as easy as we think in javascript.(My thought only)

Answer (score 1):

try to read `Angular official document,

Comment: thanks. I have searching in angularjs document. But I didn't get any topic related to my  problem. Would you please give your suggested url. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your AngularJS controller:

$scope.buyer = "Adidas";

In your html:

{{buyer}}

Comment: Yes you are right when we need to get buyer in html page. But I want to get via intellisense. i.e when I press ctrl+space system provides me a list of intellisense variable with buyer.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: You won't just know Angular once you have intellisense enabled, you will actual have to spend some effort learning it!!!

To enable intellisense follow these steps:

1) Learn Angular by reading the documentation, blog posts, looking at angular projects in Github and following the questions in this site.

2) Learn about unit testing Angular and write some tests.

3) Practice what you learn by doing a few small sites with tests.

4) Once you have done the basics and put the effort in to learn the technology you will realise that just because you use angular it will not give you intellisense in notepad.

5) Once you have this epiphany you could start using an IDE like WebStorm which offers intellisense in most Angular apps if your project is structured correctly.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/

Comment: You are write. I am using visual studio as IDE. And I am using Resharper that gives me intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

There is no intellisense for templates in Visual Studio. Yet. There is a lot of interest in this, especially within the context of Typescript and angular.

More interesting than just having intellisense for templates would be having a build fail if the variable isn't used isn't in the scope.

Unfortunately none of this exists yet.